# What could be meant by "Open output" in this context?

Tags: analog, circuit-design

Regarding [this](https://www.prelectronics.com/pdf/3102-8621-US.pdf) transducer what could be meant by "Open output"?:

[image]

The transducer is set to output 0..10V voltage.

And if the transducer sees 10V at its output through 220k resistor is it a problem for the transducer?

[image]

The reason Im asking in the circuit below there's a similar situation where 10V at node R4/R5 applies:

[image: hat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a temperature sensor with analog voltage or current output.

[image]

Different operating modes, but one is the basic process controls 4-20mA two-wire current loop meant to be fed into a remote <600Ω load resistor.  3.5mA or 23mA (NAMUR NE43) are used to indicate errors.  And 0mA indicates an open circuit or unconnected sensor.

Not the same, but relevant from [4104 Universal Signal Transmitter](https://www.prelectronics.com/filearkiv/PDF/4100%20series/4104/Manual/Arkiv/4104V100_UK.pdf):

> Therefore, a continuous measurement of the outgoing current is carried out on a 4...20 mA output signal.  If the analogue output current is 0 mA (can e.g. be caused by an open output loop)....

Same thing on the voltage side.  Take 0-10V feeding ≥10kΩ resistor.  Solid 0V or 11V (+10%) indicate errors.  <18V indicates an open circuit or unconnected sensor.

If the communication loop for the sensor is working properly in 0-10V mode, output will vary from 0V to 10V.  Actual range depends upon dip switches.  Solid 0V or 11V = sensor errors (upscale or downscale, broken sensor), while something >11V but <18V means communications loop is open.

In current mode, an open circuit with 0mA is easy to detect on receiving side, but in voltage mode, voltage on the receiving side for an open circuit is 0V.  So the >11V but <18V would be detecting the open circuit on the transmitting side to indicate an error.

In your case, you will have R5/R4 voltage divider if circuit becomes open.  Your circuit will not see 18V.

From [3000 series Users Manual](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1333/0900766b813335de.pdf)
[image: Voltage Output]

Answer (score 0):

I believe what they're telling you is that although the supply voltage is nominally 24V, you'll never see more than 18V at the output terminals, even if you leave them open-circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My main worry is when the transducer output is seeing 10V applied to its output port as in my circuit. In this case it will be like we are connecting a 9V battery to this transducer output through a 200k. So we are applying voltage to its output port where the transducer will sink around 100u. Now this reverse current will always exist. I thought 18V was related to that. type of voltage.

Comment: This confuses me because it is like connecting 9V battery to the output terminals of a function generator. An output port outputs voltage and sources current. How come we can apply voltage to an output port. So in this case the 10V at the node of R4/R5 is continuously applied to the transducer output port. Is this a problem? I mean here https://i.stack.imgur.com/bofsO.png

Comment: I can't answer that, because it depends on the internal circuitry of the interface module. I would expect that it would work, but the only way to be sure is to try it and see. You won't harm anything with 50-60 uA of current in any case. Or ask the manufacturer.